# If a client has a not-so-not-fresh consensus (<24hr), does he download the whole consensus again directly or from a relay?

Tags: relays, directory, consensus

If a client has a not-so-not-fresh consensus (<24hr), does he download the whole consensus again directly (by reaching to the directory authorities) or from his guard relay (client<=>guard relay<=>directory authority)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember consensus documents are downloaded from the directory guards. Currently, every client has three guards but that's [subject to change](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/13908).

I believe you never download the full consensus but rather only what is needed to build a circuit. (e.g. what is necessary to pick a random path through the network.)

I looked at directory protocol some time back, things may have change and I might misremember. So, you may want to take a look at [Tor directory protocol, version 3](https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/dir-spec.txt) specification yourself.

Comment: Every client now downloads only *one* guard and sticks to it.

Comment: As far as I know Tor still uses three directory guards by default. There is a [ticket](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/21006) to have it reduced to one though. (Not to be confused with the number of entry guards which indeed defaults to one.)